# How to change default app to open .url in windows 10 1903 or later? I want to use notepad

Tags: windows-10, file-association

How to change default app to open .url in windows 10 1903 or later? The new version removed the option to point to an .exe You can only use apps defined as web browsers from the Microsoft Store. I want to bypass that and open any .url .html .htm files in notepad. I don't find a simple way of doing that. I guess we have to do some registry hack?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer only for `.html` and `htm` file,

1. Right-click on a file with one of those extensions, then select Open with.
2. Select Choose another app, select Notepad if it is listed.
3. If Notepad is not listed, select More apps -> then select Notepad.
4. If Notepad is not listed after step 3, select "Look for another app on this PC". Go where Notepad is located, select it. Click Open.

Don't forget to check "Always use this app to open .html files".

Comment: This does not work with .url files.
It works for "normal" types but for weblinks, windows decides you cannot use a local app. Only apps from the appstore tagged as web browsers. Try it yourself with a .url link on a veresion of windows >1903

Comment: @bigfurrymonster The answer s only for htm and html files not url.